# Django Grappelli for django 1.5.1

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli

I am trying to use django-grappelli with django version 1.5.1

but after setup, all the requirements for grappelli, i am having the following error.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/
'firstof' is not a valid tag or filter in tag library 'future'


In template C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\grappelli\templates\admin\base.html, error at line 1


{% load admin_static %}{% load firstof from future %}{% load i18n grp_tags %}
```

Ideas?

Comment: Which grappelli version you are using ?

Comment: Read about [versions and compatibility](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#versions-and-compatibility).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grappelli 2.4.8 (compatible with django 1.5) does not include firstof from future, grappelli 2.5.0 (compatible with django 1.6) does.

reference link https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli/issues/407